# Return value not changing in business logic layer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had to use three tier architecture in my application. I have to get data access layer return values in my business access layer but I'm not able to get the changing values in my business access layer.

**My Code Behind page**

```
  protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    obj.empReg(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, isactive, Convert.ToInt32(hdntest.Value));

                    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                }                               

            }
```

**My Business Access Layer:-**

```
 public int empReg(string username, string password, int isactive, int returncode)
        {
           return obj.EmpRegistration(username, password, isactive, returncode);

        }
```

**My Data Access Layer:-**

```
 public int EmpRegistration(string username, string password, int isactive, int returncode)
        {
            isactive = 1;
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeDB"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_RegisterationUser", connection);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");
                SqlParameter paramusername = new SqlParameter("@Username", username);
                com.Parameters.Add(paramusername);
                SqlParameter parampassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);
                com.Parameters.Add(parampassword);
                SqlParameter paramisactive = new SqlParameter("@isactive", isactive);
                com.Parameters.Add(paramisactive);
                connection.Open();               
                returncode = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

                return returncode;
            }

        }
```

Here everything is working fine but that `returncode` parameter value does not change in my business layer. I don't know how to get that `returncode` parameter in my business access layer.

Comment: where is the returncode parameter here?

Comment: you are calling `obj.empReg()` from the code behind and you return an integer from that method without using it!? so why are you returning an integer when you are not using it ?

Comment: Do you get any exception in your `EmpRegistration` method?

Answer (score 0):

You are not Getting/Assigning the return value anywhere.Probably you are looking for something like this,

```
int Result = obj.empReg(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, isactive, Convert.ToInt32(hdntest.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need following changes, There is no need of sending returncode in parameter when you are not using it.

**Code Behind**:

```
 protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
     //...      
     int iReturnCode = obj.empReg(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, isactive);

     //if(iReturnCode > 0)
     Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");                                        
 }
```

**Business Layer**:

```
 public int empReg(string username, string password, int isactive)
 {
       return obj.EmpRegistration(username, password, isactive);
 }
```

**Data Access Layer**:

```
public int EmpRegistration(string username, string password, int isactive)
{ 
   try
   {
     //...
     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
     {
          //...            
          return Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());                
     }
   }
   catch{ return -1; }       
 }
```